# GitHub Repo Contributor Missing from Repo Homepage

Tags: github

This question is with regards to this public [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/aritraghsh09/GaMPEN)

The homepage of the repository lists only two contributors (right panel); but if you look at the [commit graph](https://github.com/aritraghsh09/GaMPEN/graphs/contributors), you see three contributors.

I cannot seem to figure out why contributor #2, who is present in the contributor graph, is missing  from the homepage.

The contributor whose name is missing has contributions which are much more than 24 hours old. All existing questions talk about contirbutors being missing overall, but I couldn't find anything which was talking about a mismatch like this one.